# Write to a text File C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, streamwriter, sharing-violation

```
    void Update(){
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Application.dataPath + @"/SaveFiles/ControlStick.txt", true);
    writer.WriteLine(inputVector); //+ "," + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);
}
```

This is the relevant code.
I need to write to a unity file without overwriting the lines again and again.

This is my specific error.
***IOException: Sharing violation on path G:\Physics Platformer\Assets\SaveFiles\ControlStick.txt
System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean anonymous, FileOptions options) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:320)
System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor (System.String path, Boolean append, System.Text.Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/StreamWriter.cs:124)
System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor (System.String path, Boolean append)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.StreamWriter:.ctor (string,bool)
VirtualJoystick.Update () (at Assets/UBX-master/UBX-master/VirtualJoystick.cs:51)***
To explain, i use Application.dataPath to get the installation path of my unity game when it has been exported and installed. Input vector is a Vector3.

Comment: Is it right to put this code inside the `Update()` method? Try to put the variable declaration inside the `Start()` and use only the `WriteLine()` in the `Update()`.

Comment: ok i will try  .